# How to filter based on a nested Django JSONField?

Tags: django, filter, nested, django-jsonfield

I have a json field for a model in my Django app that typically has nested json in it. I read that to filter on a JSONfield, you would use contains on the filter for whatever value you are looking for, but I'm not getting any results back even though I know the value does exist in the JSONField. Is there an extra step I need to use for nested json in a json field?

JSON Field "Field name is Content "

```
"content": {
    "documents": [
        {
             "id": "378",
             "name": "Test.pdf",
             "mediaFile": "http://localhost:8000/media/file.pdf"
        }
    ]
}
```

Query:

```
document_modules = 
 WMDocumentModule.objects.filter(content__documents__contains={'id': "378"})

>>> document_modules: <QuerySet []>
```

Comment: Can you try `WMDocumentModule.objects.filter(content__documents__contains=[{'id': "378"}])`? It looks like the closest to `__values__contains` modify on `ArrayField`.

Comment: Sorry for the late replay. That did work ! thank you : )